# Angular do not parse API correctly ( PHP on server site )

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I ask my API for data as it used to be,
I think my API is not displaying data correctly but I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code

JS looks like:

```
function getSoapData(){
    var myPromise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/v1/Soap.php?vin=' + $scope.vin
    });
    return myPromise;
};

$scope.doWE = function(){
    getData().success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.cases = data;
        getSoapData().then(function(soapData){
            $scope.soapCases = soapData;
            console.log(soapData);
        });
    });
};
```

PHP looks like:

```
     $data = array (
            "caseNumber" =>$claim['@attributes']['id'],
            "date_created" =>$claim['country'],
            "country" =>$claim['creation'],
            "currency" =>$claim ['specific']['currency'],
            "insurer_memberid" =>$claim['insurance']['id'],
            "laborcosts" =>$claim ['specific']['partsCost'],
            "model" =>$claim ['specific']['model_name'],
            "orgName" =>$claim['insurance']['name'],
            "paintLabor" =>$claim['specific']['paintmaterial'],
            "totalcosts" =>$claim ['assessment']['damage-value']
        );
        echo $this->convertToJson($data);
```

and data which comes looks like:

```
{"caseNumber":"2003-09-30.BEL.BE01001129143","date_created":"BEL","country":"2003-09-30","currency":null,"insurer_memberid":"1671","laborcosts":null,"model":null,"orgName":"ZELIA INSURANCE","paintLabor":null,"totalcosts":"11157.02"}
```

However, I get this error:

> Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received:
>   {"data":"Array","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://example.com/api/v1/Soap.php?vin=VF38BRHZE80728805","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}

Error expect problem on this line:
`<tr ng-repeat-start="soapCase in soapCases | orderBy:sortField:reverse">`

It says it expects an array but didn't get it. I really don't think it should expect an array instead of JSON.

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I have one similar function `getdata()` function that looks like:

```
function getData(){
   var myPromise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.audahistory.cz/api/v1/History.php?vin=' + $scope.vin
    });
    return myPromise;
};
```

with result:
http://pastebin.com/s31jhnip
but this works correctly

Comment: `$scope.soapCases = JSON.parse(soapData);`

Comment: hey @Steve thanks for answer, I just try it with same result :(
basicly I have same function for getData() just another endpoint and works correctly, result from that endpoint can be found here: http://pastebin.com/s31jhnip

Comment: How about `$scope.soapCases.push(soapData);` - its not exacly clear what you are trying to do, replace or add to `$scope.soapCases` Also the names are weird, this clearly isnt soap, its standard json

Comment: Are, just saw your edit, i know what the problem is - the above code sends a single json object, not an array. Either use the `push` code in my above comment, or send a single element array in the php: `$data = array (array(
            "caseNumber" =>$claim['@attributes']['id'],
            ...
        ));`

Comment: @Steve name is Soap because data come from SOAP but it's parsed by PHP before.

Comment: Okey I just try both ways, way with PHP double array return unexepected token o and push return: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
            getSoapData().then(function(soapData){
                $scope.soapCases.push(soapData);
                console.log(soapData);
            });

Comment: `unexepected token o` Huh? Are you sure you added the outer array correctly? Perhaps it would be more logical to add the outer array in the call to json encode: `echo $this->convertToJson(array($data));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97863/discussion-between-andurit-and-steve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP code you're building an array, but indexed with strings, so it gets converted to a JSON object. ng-repeat expects array, so someting like:

```
[{"caseNumber":"2003-09-30.BEL.BE01001129143","date_created":"BEL","country":"2003-09-30","currency":null,"insurer_memberid":"1671","laborcosts":null,"model":null,"orgName":"ZELIA INSURANCE","paintLabor":null,"totalcosts":"11157.02"}]
```

So in PHP you should insert this associative array into normal array:

```
$result = array();
$result[] = $data;
```

And then try to convert it into JSON.

```
echo $this->convertToJson($result);
```

If there's no data returned you have two options:

- Return an empty array converted to JSON
- Return HTTP 404 error response and handle that in Angular.

Comment: Hi @scareddragon I really appriciate your help however  this return same error as before :(

Comment: Can you paste JSON response from the API after the change?

Comment: sure, json can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/DYEkrQpp
Error is displayed even if server return blanked result ( no data for specific VIN )

Comment: This looks ok. How does this output look when there's no data?

Comment: blanked response no data nothing at all :)
Isn't it double array problem on that pastebin?

Comment: You have two options in that case:

1. Return an empty array converted to JSON
2. Return HTTP 404 error from your API and handle it in angular.

Empty reponse is incorrect.

Comment: Okey I just find it now, you was right from start but there was one additional fail, i return  $scope.soapCases = soapData; but it was a problem because use .then(function(soapData) so I had to use                 $scope.soapCases = soapData.data;